# Angular configuration when using Jest

Tags: angular, jestjs

I've recently switched to Jest for unit testing

Previously I was doing this:

```
ng test --configuration=unit-tests
```

But I am not sure how to run my Jest tests with an Angular configuration, I want something like this:

```
jest --configuration=unit-tests
```

How do I run my Jest tests with a specified Angular configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **angular.json** file specify jest runner for **test** architect:

```
"test": {
   "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
   "options": {}
},
```

I assume that you have installed it, when switched to jest

Comment: thanks this is good to know and I will use this in my personal project, however, my works project is too far gone for this to ever work - ill have to try and hack it - but much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

1. Created a setupJest.ts file in the root and import
   jest-preset-angular
2. add the Jest configuration in the package.json

```html
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setupJest.ts"
    ]
  }
```

3. modify the test script to use Jest instead of ng test.
4. run npm test